# If a polynomial $P$ has only real roots, so does $P'-2xP$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Let $P$ be a polynomial such that all of the roots of $P$ are real. Prove that all the roots of $P'-2xP$ are also real. I know a proof for this fact but it is very computational and messy. Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Maybe try Rouches theorem.

Answer (score 31):

Let $g(x)=P(x)e^{-x^2}$. Then
$$g'(x)=P'(x)\cdot e^{-x^2}+P(x)\cdot (-2x)e^{-x^2}= (P'(x)-2xP(x))e^{-x^2}. $$
We may consider $g$ to be extended to the infinities per $g(\pm\infty)=0$ because the exponential function outweighs the polynomial factor.

First assume that the roots of $P$ are distinct. Then $g$ has $n+2$ distinct zeroes, namely the $n$ zeroes of $P$ and $\pm\infty$. Between any two consecutive of these, Rolle gives us a zero of $g'$, hence a root of $P'-2xP$. This gives us $n+1$ distinct real roots, and as this corresponds to the degree, the claim follows.

You may contemplate how to make the Rolle argument rigorous when $x=\pm\infty$ is involved, and what to look out for when $P$ has roots of higher multiplicity. For the latter, I suggest to add a tiny "perturbation" to $P$ that splits multiple roots up into separate roots, and let the perturbation tend to $0$.

Comment: +1, straight from The Book.

Comment: Incidentally, this solution was inspired by @yugikaiba's (deleted, wrong) answer  that was based on a misunderstanding of the problem statement but mentioned $e^{x^2}$

Comment: One more proof that when trying and solving problems one has to keep moving, even if sometimes the moves are in the wrong direction.

Comment: This is also rather interesting from an engineering perspective. Quite often we use gaussian integral scalar product. And the Hermite polynomials are orthogonal under it. Dammit, maybe that is what the other guy was trying to write but I was too fast at bashing it. Now I probably scared him away and he won't come back :-/

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you put a little more details in the case where there are roots of higher multiplicity? I agree with everything else.

Answer (score 5):

May assume that $P$ has $n$ distinct roots $a_1< \ldots < a_n$, otherwise the multiple roots are also roots of the new equation.  The equation is equivalent to $\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} = 2 x$, that is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x-a_i} = 2x$$
On each interval $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ the LHS decreases from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$, while the  RHS increases between two finite values. Therefore, the equality is achieved exactly once in each $(a_i, a_{i+1})$. Now, on the interval $(a_{n}, \infty)$, LHS decreases from $+\infty$ to $0$, while RHS increases from a finite value to $+ \infty$. So we have exactly one root in $(a_{n}, \infty)$. Similarly in $(-\infty, a_1)$. We conclude that the equation has exactly $n+1$ solutions.  Note that we can substitute $2 x$ with any continuous increasing function with infinite limits. The case of a constant is also interesting.
The picture for  $P(x)=(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)$ is below.

[image]

Note: @Hagen von Eitzen: 's method works for any functions $P(x)$, since
$(e^{-L(x)}P(x))' = e^{-L(x)}( P'(x) - l(x) P(x))$, so we do get a root ( an odd number) between two (consecutive) roots of $P(x)$. If $e^{-L(x)}P(x)$ is $0$ at $\pm \infty$ $  we do get extra roots.

Does our method work for functions $P(x)$ that are not polynomial? Say $a$, $b$ are consecutive simple roots of $P(x)$. Then $P'(a)$, $P'(b)$ are of opposite value so on the interval $(a,b)$ the function $\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}$ ranges from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$.  At $\pm \infty$ it's about the behaviour of $\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}$. The method seems to still work.

$\bf{Added:}$ Say we are want to show that $(x-\alpha) P'(x) + \lambda P(x)=0$ has all roots real ( $\lambda> 0$ or $\lambda < -n$) (Laguerre).  Consider the derivative of $|x-\alpha|^{\lambda} P(x)$.  Or we can do the analysis with $\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}$.